# How to enforce Eclipse Applet Viewer to perform security checks?

Tags: java, eclipse, security, applet

I develop applet in Eclipse and it runs okay using default in-built Applet Viewer. It does not work in browser because of many security exceptions. So with every code change I have to rebuild the jar and run it in browser (IE) to test.

How can I enforce Eclipse Applet Viewer to use same security policies as IE browser for applets?

I have tried to specify JVM argument as follows, but still applet is successful in Eclipse, but I need it to fail because of security policy.

```
-Djava.security.policy=="java.policy.applet"
```

Comment: One 'quick check' you can do is to establish a `SecurityManager` in a `try/catch` in the `init()`.  If the applet has a security manager, the `catch` will be used, if it does not, the SM will be installed.  I cannot guarantee it will be exactly the same as the applet security manager, but should provide the same general experience.  BTW - I have not put this as an answer because. 1) It is a hack, & 2) I'd like to see an IDE based solution as well.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, do you mean `SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();` or `SecurityManager appsm = new SecurityManager();` ?

Comment: I mean `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager())`

Comment: @AndrewThompson, does not seem to have effect in Eclipse. Expection is not thrown for it, btw.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, in applet I have called `checkConnect` and in stack I can see that it is called `sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager`. Is there any option I can construct and apply it?

Comment: Huh.  Turns out I was wrong.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse automatically creates a policy file "java.policy.applet" in the root of your compiled project which grants all permissions. And its set the JVM parameter "-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet". It seems that this behavior cannot be disabled.

You can try to add the same JVM parameter with a different policy file, however Eclipse adds its parameter after yours, and the JVM seem to consider just the last one. So this does not help.

But, if you create your own policy file (java.policy.applet) in the root of your source folder, Eclipse does not overwrite it. You can copy %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\java.policy to get the real java policies.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable Security Manager.Below JVM option will do that for you:

−Djava.security.manager

Enabling security manager will use the default security settings (for ex: java.policy) from whatever Java version your eclipse is using.

IE might be using its own JRE that is not same as your Eclipse JRE version. You've two options here.

1) Either make your browser use the same JRE as Eclipse by changing JRE version of your IE. In Windows7, click on Control panel>Java> (Select Java Tab)> Add JRE path installed on your system that Eclipse uses

2) Change Eclipse JRE environment to use same JRE as your IE.

−Djava.security.policy=java.policy PayrollApp

Comment: `−Djava.security.manager` only has no effect. And I don't think it is a matter of JRE.

Comment: `−Djava.security.policy=java.policy PayrollApp` what means PayrollApp in here?